# Check whether domain is registered

Tags: python, dns

I'm trying to make a script that returns unregistered domains. I'm working in Python 2.7. I've read that the module `whois` should be able to do that but the code I've written raises an error.

Code:

```
import whois
domains = ['http://www.example.com']

for dom in domains:
    domain = whois.Domain(dom)
    print domain.registrar
```

Error:

```
  domain = whois.Domain(dom)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\whois\_3_adjust.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.name               = data['domain_name'][0].strip().lower()
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Have you any idea what could be wrong? Or can you give me a better solution?

EDIT: I tried the pythonwhois module but it returns an error too.

EDIT2: According to one solution here, on SO, I've tried to use `pywhois`, this code raises an error too.

```
import pywhois
w = pywhois.whois('google.com')
w.expiration_date
```

ERROR:

```
w = pywhois.whois('google.com')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'whois'
```

Comment: Did whois module worked for you?

Comment: @Ajay No, it did not. It raises error, something with subprocess so it can be another problem.

Comment: Did you use pip to install or any other method?
I'm on ubuntu and used pip to install.And that code worked for me.

Comment: The domain name tested should not include neither `http://` nor `www.`.

Comment: *This does not work*. It's extremely easy to test this, simply put in a domain you know is taken and you'll quickly realize this module cannot be used to test if it's available. As an example, try putting in `aa.nz`, `whois` will say this is available when it simply isn't

Answer (score 18, accepted):

with pythonwhois if you favor, it could be

```
>>> import pythonwhois  # i'm using this http://cryto.net/pythonwhois
>>> domains = ['google.com', 'stackoverflow.com']
>>> for dom in domains:
...     details = pythonwhois.get_whois(dom)
...     print details['contacts']['registrant']
```

which returns a dictionary

```
{'city': u'Mountain View', 
'fax': u'+1.6506188571', 
'name': u'Dns Admin', 
'state': u'CA', 
'phone': u'+1.6502530000', 
'street': u'Please contact contact- admin@google.com, 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway', 
'country': u'US', 
'postalcode': u'94043', 
'organization': u'Google Inc.', 
'email': u'dns-admin@google.com'}

{'city': u'New York', 
 'name': u'Sysadmin Team', 
 'state': u'NY', 
 'phone': u'+1.2122328280', 
 'street': u'1 Exchange Plaza , Floor 26', 
 'country': u'US', 
 'postalcode': u'10006', 
 'organization': u'Stack Exchange, Inc.', 
 'email': u'sysadmin-team@stackoverflow.com'}
```

edit: i checked your `whois`
this code worked for me.

```
>>> import whois
>>> domains = ['google.com', 'stackoverflow.com']
>>> for dom in domains:
...     domain = whois.query(dom)
...     print domain.name, domain.registrar
... 
google.com MARKMONITOR INC.
stackoverflow.com NAME.COM, INC.
```

this api uses unix/linux's whois shell command and as it shown [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uwhois.htm#03) you shouldn't add `http://` before domain name. or if you have a unix/linux machine test this:

```
$ whois google.com

Whois Server Version 2.0

Domain names in the .com and .net domains can now be registered
with many different competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net
for detailed information ...
```

but with http (it is maybe because of http(s) is a just a protocol type, and doesn't have any realiton with domain name itself)

```
$ whois http://google.com
No whois server is known for this kind of object.
```

Answer (score 8):

I've had issues with python-whois in Python 3, but Python 2 works fine for me using the following code.

First, I would recommend uninstalling any whois module(s) you might have installed. Both python-whois (0.6.1) and whois (0.7) use the same `import whois`, which created some additional confusion for me.

Next, install python-whois through Command Prompt, Terminal, etc.

`pip install python-whois`

Once installed, enter the following code in your preferred python IDE.

```
"""
Python = 2.79
OS = Windows 10
IDE = PyCharm 4.5
PyPIPackage = python-whois 0.6.1
"""

import whois
url = 'example.com'
w = whois.whois(url)
print w
```

The result is a dictionary.

```
{
  "updated_date": "2015-08-14 00:00:00", 
  "status": [
    "clientDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited", 
    "clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited", 
    "clientUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited"
  ], 
  "name": null, 
  "dnssec": null, 
  "city": null, 
  "expiration_date": "2016-08-13 00:00:00", 
...
...
...
  "address": null, 
  "name_servers": [
    "A.IANA-SERVERS.NET", 
    "B.IANA-SERVERS.NET"
  ], 
  "org": null, 
  "creation_date": "1995-08-14 00:00:00", 
  "emails": null
}
```

Comment: According to PEP 008 - it's probably not a good idea to use dunderscored variable names. Is there a reason you've used them here that I'm not familiar with? (I hardly use any IDEs).

Comment: @bjd2385 I removed the underscores and replaced it with a block comments so there wouldn't be any confusion since those 4 lines aren't meant to be variables. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 7):

### Installation

```
pip install pythonwhois
```

You might need to execute `pip3 install pythonwhois --user` or something similar.

### Code

```
import pythonwhois


def is_registered(site):
    """Check if a domain has an WHOIS record."""
    details = pythonwhois.get_whois(site)
    return not details['raw'][0].startswith('No match for')


names = ['google', 'af35foobar90']
for name in names:
    site = '{}.com'.format(name)
    print('{}: {}'.format(site, is_registered(site)))
```

Comment: `pythonwhois` seems broken. I had to use `pythonwhois-alt`

Answer (score 6):

The whois project has been moved to [github](https://github.com/DDarko/python-whois/), you can install it using `pip install python-whois`:

```
domains = ['http://www.example.com']
from whois import whois

print(whois(domains[0]))

{'updated_date': datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 0, 0), 'status': ['clientDeleteProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited', 'clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited', 'clientUpdateProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited'], 'name': None, 'dnssec': None, 'city': None, 'expiration_date': datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 13, 0, 0), 'zipcode': None, 'domain_name': 'EXAMPLE.COM', 'country': None, 'whois_server': ['whois.enetica.com.au', 'whois.godaddy.com', 'whois.domain.com', 'whois.iana.org'], 'state': None, 'registrar': ['ENETICA PTY LTD', 'GODADDY.COM, LLC', 'DOMAIN.COM, LLC', 'RESERVED-INTERNET ASSIGNED NUMBERS AUTHORITY'], 'referral_url': ['http://www.enetica.com.au', 'http://registrar.godaddy.com', 'http://www.domain.com', 'http://res-dom.iana.org'], 'address': None, 'name_servers': ['A.IANA-SERVERS.NET', 'B.IANA-SERVERS.NET'], 'org': None, 'creation_date': datetime.datetime(1995, 8, 14, 0, 0), 'emails': None}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whois/0.7) and worked for me.Domain name should be like mysite.com(not http://www.example.com)

```
>>> import whois
>>> domains = ['google.com']
>>> 
>>> for dom in domains:
...     domain = whois.query(dom)
...     print domain.registrar 
... 



MARKMONITOR INC.
```

EDIT:1 I don't know why it is not working for others and getting errors.
I'm posting a screenshot of my terminal
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'registrar'` for your exact example