# Domain name detection

Tags: python, list

I want to get the filter of the legit domain names using this Python code.
I can't see any problem with the code and have consulted a lot of websites. It is not able to separate the right and wrong domain names.

```py
def getDomains():
    with open('domains.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for domainName in f.read().splitlines():
            domains.append(domainName)

def run():
    for dom in domains:
       if dom is not None and dom != '':
           details = pythonwhois.get_whois(dom)
           if str(details) is None:
               unavailable.append(dom)
           else:
               available.append(dom)
```

### the result should be like:

### available domains

google.com
youtube.com

---

### unavailable domains

xcdv345.hgt.com
letstrythis12398.net

Comment: What error or problem is coming...

Comment: I am not getting the filter:

Comment: -----------------------------
Unavailable Domains: 
-----------------------------


-----------------------------
Available Domains: 
-----------------------------
google.com
adomainthatshouldbeavailable.com
check-domains-py.com
onfcbdkmccfcfaad.co

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check whether domain is registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773003/check-whether-domain-is-registered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the `id` key exists in the returned `dictionary` from `pythonwhois.get_whois()`

**Example:**

```py
import pythonwhois

domains = ['google.com', 'i-n-v-a-l-i-d.com']

for dom in domains:
  if dom is not None and dom != '':
    details = pythonwhois.get_whois(dom)

    # Check if 'id' key exists in the 'details' dictionary
    # if the 'id' key exists the domain is already registerd
    if 'id' in details:
      print('{} available'.format(dom))
    else:
      print('{} unavailable'.format(dom))
```

**Output:**

```
google.com available
i-n-v-a-l-i-d.com unavailable
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if the domain isn't registered, `pythonwhois.get_whois` isn't `None`.

Try printing the result of `pythonwhois.get_whois('jjj876686.njerfjr')`, for example the field `contacts` is always present (the result, and str(result), are different from `None`) (see http://cryto.net/pythonwhois/usage.html#pythonwhois_get_whoisdomainnormalized)

Comment: even if i do "if str(details) is  not None:" the problem still exists.

Comment: As I said, details is ALWAYS different from None, `str(details) is not None` is always True. I think you've to check if `details['contacts']['registrant']` exists and not None, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773003/check-whether-domain-is-registered

Comment: I have tried these cases too, " if details['contacts']['registrant'] is  not None:" and " if details is  not None:"

Comment: `details['contacts']['registrant']` for `onfcbdkmccfcfaad.co` and `adomainthatshouldbeavailable.com` is None, where is the pb ?

Answer (score 1):

The line `if str(details) is  None:` will always be `False`, even if `details` is `None`.

Running `str(None)` gives you the string `'None'`, which is not the same as the value `None`:

```
str(None) is None  # False
None is None       # True
```