# How to quickly check if domain exists?

Tags: python

I have a large list of domains and I need to check if domains are available now. I do it like this:

```
import requests
list_domain = ['google.com', 'facebook.com']
for domain in list_domain:
    result = requests.get(f'http://{domain}', timeout=10)
    if result.status_code == 200:
        print(f'Domain {domain} [+++]')
    else:
        print(f'Domain {domain} [---]')
```

But the check is too slow. Is there a way to make it faster? Maybe someone knows an alternative method for checking domains for existence?

Comment: Well, this is somewhat ban manners on the internet, but you could look into doing the requests in parallel (using multiprocessing) or asynchronously.

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773003/check-whether-domain-is-registered/29773604

Comment: @venky__ This answer doesn't suit me. These examples do not work for me on Windows + Python3.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check which domains are available, the more correct approach would be to catch the `ConnectionError` from the `requests` module, because even if you get a response code that is not `200`, the fact that there is a response means that there is a server associated with that domain. Hence, the domain is taken.

This is not full proof in terms of checking for domain availability, because a domain might be taken, but may not have appropriate A record associated with it, or the server may just be down for the time being.

The code below is asynchronous as well.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError

def validate_existence(domain):
    try:
        response = requests.get(f'http://{domain}', timeout=10)
    except ConnectionError:
        print(f'Domain {domain} [---]')
    else:
        print(f'Domain {domain} [+++]')


list_domain = ['google.com', 'facebook.com', 'nonexistent_domain.test']

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(validate_existence, list_domain)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the socket library to determine if a domain has a DNS entry, this is quick and may be a good enough proxy:

```
>>> import socket
>>> 
>>> addr = socket.gethostbyname('google.com')
>>> addr
'74.125.193.100'
>>> socket.gethostbyname('googl42652267e.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
>>>
```

```
import socket

def check_dns(hostname: str) -> bool:
    try:
        socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
        return True
    except socket.error:
        return False

assert check_dns(hostname='www.google.com') is True
assert check_dns(hostname='www.fhsdfh2462fgfwegryt2g.com') is False
```

Or you can use the [python-whois library](https://github.com/DannyCork/python-whois) to check if the domain is registered.

Comment: This only checks if there is a DNS entry, not if the domain is registered.

Comment: I added some clarification,

Answer (score 1):

You can do that via "[requests-futures](https://pypi.org/project/requests-futures/)" module.
requests-futures runs Asynchronously, If you have a average internet connection it can check 8-10 url per second (Based on my experience).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is run the script multiple times but add only a limited amount of domains to each to make it speedy.

Answer (score -1):

Use scrapy it is way faster and by default it yields only 200 response until you over ride it so in your case follow me

```
pip install scrapy
```

After installing in your project folder user terminal to creat project

```
Scrapy startproject projectname projectdir
```

It will create folder name projectdir

Now

```
cd projectdir
```

Inside projectdir enter

```
scrapy genspider mydomain mydomain.com
```

Now navigate to spiders folder open  mydomain.py

Now add few lines of code

```
import scrapy


class MydomainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "mydomain"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'facebook.com',
            'Google.com',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
       yield { ‘Available_Domains’ : response.url}
```

Now back to projectdir and run

```
scrapy crawl mydomain -o output.csv
```

You will have all the working domains having status code 200 in output.csv file

For more [see](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)