# AttributeError: module 'whois' has no attribute 'whois'

Tags: python, attributeerror, whois, pywhois

I am running my ML code and getting this error-

```
    Enter website name=> www.google.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dphishing.py", line 12, in <module>
    p2.category2(website)
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\Detect_Phishing_Website\p2.py", line 8, in category2
    page = whois.whois(website)
AttributeError: module 'whois' has no attribute 'whois'
```

My code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import p1
import p2
import p3
import p4
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np

website = str(input("Enter website name=> "))
p1.category1(website)
p2.category2(website)
p3.category3(website)
p4.category4(website)


read = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Anushree\Desktop\college\4th year project\Detect_Phishing_Website\phishing5.txt',header = None,sep = ',')
read = read.iloc[:,:-1].values
dataset = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Anushree\Desktop\college\4th year project\Detect_Phishing_Website\Training Dataset1.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:,:-1].values  
y = dataset.iloc[:,-1].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2,random_state = 1001)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 10,criterion = "mse",random_state = 2)
regressor.fit(X_train,y_train)                             

y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)


from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
accuracy = cross_val_score(estimator = regressor,X=X_train,y=y_train,cv = 5)
accuracy.mean()
accuracy.std()


Detect_phishing_website = regressor.predict(read)

if Detect_phishing_website == 1:
    print("legitimate website")
elif Detect_phishing_website == 0:
    print ('suspicious website')
else:
    print('phishing website')
```

The code of file p2.py is:

```
import re
import whois

def category2(website):
        
    file_obj = open(r'C:\Users\Anushree\Desktop\college\4th year project\Detect_Phishing_Website\phishing5.txt','a')
    #8 Domain Registration Length
    page = whois.whois(website)
    if type(page.expiration_date) == list:
        domain_reg_len = (page.expiration_date[0] - page.creation_date[0]).days
    else:
        domain_reg_len = (page.expiration_date - page.creation_date).days
    #print domain_reg_len
    if domain_reg_len <= 365:
        file_obj.write('-1,')
    else:
        file_obj.write('1,')
    #9 Using Non-Standard Port 
    match_port = re.search(':[//]+[a-z]+.[a-z0-9A-Z]+.[a-zA-Z]+:([0-9#]*)',website)
    if match_port:
        print (match_port.group())
        if match_port.group(1) == '#':#represent multiple ports are active on url
            file_obj.write('-1,')
        else:
            file_obj.write('1,')
    else:
        file_obj.write('1,')
    file_obj.close()
```

I have already tried uninstalling whois and then reinstalling python-whois using the command pip install python-whois. But that hasn't helped with the error.

How can I understand what is going wrong, and how I can correct it?

Comment: check that answer for proper usage of `whois` and `pythonwhois` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29773604/4481312

Comment: Does [this](https://pypi.org/project/whois/) help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check whether domain is registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29773003/check-whether-domain-is-registered)

Comment: It appears to be a known issue with packages confusions. I have deleted my answer and mark it possible dublicate

Answer (score 2):

**Reason for your error:** 
You have not installed the whois command on your system. 
Ubuntu: Use `sudo apt install whois` 
Windows: Download and install from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/whois)

First uninstall any `whois` module with `pip uninstall whois` and `pip uninstall python-whois`

**Solution 1**: Use [python-whois](https://pypi.org/project/python-whois/)

Install `python-whois` with `pip install python-whois` 
Then make sure you already installed the `whois` command on your machine. 
Then your code should work.

**Solution 2**: Use [whois](https://pypi.org/project/whois/)

Install `whois` command on your machine. If you are on ubuntu `sudo apt install whois` will do. 
Install whois module with `pip install whois`, 
Then use `whois.query()` instead of `whois.whois()` in your code.

[Source](https://github.com/DannyCork/python-whois/issues/139)

Comment: Should I first uninstall Python-whois for whois to work properly?

Comment: @Anu2045 yep, just do `pip uninstall python-whois`

Comment: The command pip install whois installed whois-0.9.7. And on running the file Dphishing.py, the error is persistent. Please help

Comment: Yes. I uninstalled python-whois and have installed whois as you instructed. But getting the same error- Enter website name=> www.google.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dphishing.py", line 12, in <module>
    p2.category2(website)
  File "C:\xampp\htdocs\Detect_Phishing_Website\p2.py", line 9, in category2
    page = whois.whois(website)
AttributeError: module 'whois' has no attribute 'whois'

Comment: No the problem is still there. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: @Anu2045 did you install whois command on your windows? If not, go [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/whois) to download and install whois command for shell